# map with fixed (const) keys and changeable data?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have map like this:

```
struct cmp_str
{
   bool operator()(char const *a, char const *b)
   {
      return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0;
   }
};
std::map<char *, std::atomic<bool>, cmp_str> my_map;
```

I add keys to `my_map` only during creation,
this is important because of I use `my_map` from multiply threads
without locking.

I want compiler to check that nobody add keys to `my_map` after creation.

But I can not define `my_map` as `const`, because of then I can not change
data. Is it possible somehow to make half `const` map?

I mean it have fixed number of keys and all them defined during creation,
but it is possible to change data (not keys) in map?

I thought about holding `std::atomic<bool> *const` in `const std::map`,
but I have to manually free memory after this. Smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` not helps here.

Any ideas how to make half `const` map with help of `std::` from `c++11`?

Comment: Why does `unique_ptr` "not helps here" [sic]?

Comment: @Yakk I thought that I can not assign value pointed by `const unique_ptr`, but looks like I am wrong here?

Comment: `const std::unique_ptr<T>`, or `std::unique_ptr<T const>`?